# Showing equality of sigma fields generated by subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: measure-theory

**Problem:** Let $D$ be the collection of all finite unions of disjoint intervals of the form $(a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $D$ is a ring in $\mathbb{R}$ and that $\sigma(D) = \sigma(O)$ where $O$ is the collection of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Here $\sigma(A)$ denotes the minimal $\sigma$-field over $A$.

Now to show that $D$ is a ring I want to show closure under unions and set differences, so I thought to just write the following.

> Let $A,B \in D$ so that  $A = \bigcup_{i =1}^n A_i$ where $A_i$ are disjoint intervals of the form $(a_i,b_i]$, and $B = \bigcup_{j=1}^m B_j$ where $B_j$ are disjoint intervals of the form $(a_j,b_j]$. Then
> $$
>  A \cup B = \left(\bigcup_{i =1}^n A_i\right) \cup \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n B_j\right) = A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n \cup B_1 \cup \dots \cup B_m.
>  $$
> Evidently $A \cup B$ is the finite union of disjoint intervals of the required form.

But after reflection is this evident or am I just trying to finish too early. Because in the case where the sets in the union overlap, you still just pick the largest subset. For example $[(1,2] \cup (\pi,6]) \cup [(1,5] \cup (6,9] ]= (1,5] \cup (6,9]$, which is again a disjoint union of sets of the correct form. Is this straightforward enough or should it be proved?

Also to show that $\sigma(D) = \sigma(O)$ are there any recommendations? It seems trivial by the fact that the minimal $\sigma$-field is always defined and hence $\sigma(D)$ and $\sigma(O)$ both exist, but since they are both sigma fields over $\mathbb{R}$ we can just use $\sigma(D) \subseteq \sigma(O)$ and $\sigma(O) \subseteq \sigma(D)$ by definition of *minimal* $\sigma$-field, but I imagine I'm missing something because this argument seems too easy?

Thanks in advance for the clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first idea is right to show that $D$ is a ring.

Further $\sigma(A)$ is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra, which contains $A$, as you mentioned correctly. But $\sigma(D)$ and $\sigma(O)$ are the smallest with respect to containing set, here $D$ and $O$ and not over $\mathbb{R}$.

A basic argument to show that to $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_1),\sigma(\mathcal{E}_2)$ are equal is trough their generator $\mathcal{E}_1,\mathcal{E}_2$. The idea is that if $\mathcal{E}_i \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}_j)$ then because of minimality it holds $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_i)\subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}_j)$.

One way to see that this holds in your case is:

1. $\sigma(O)=\sigma \{(a,b): (a,b) \text{ open interval in }\mathbb{R}\}$
2. $(a,b]=\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}(a,b+\frac{1}{k})$
3. $(a,b)=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}(a,b-\frac{1}{k}]$

Comment: Ah alright. Any hints on how to proceed for the second part?

Comment: @AndreyYanyuk I edit my post. Thought you meant a $\sigma$-ring.

Comment: Just to confirm, the idea is that if $\mathcal{E}_i \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{E}_j)$ by the minimality of $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_i)$ we can conclude that since $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_j)$ is a sigma field containing $\mathcal{E}_i$ we must have $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_i) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{E}_j)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Do you know how to proceed now?